# How to write String.Contains in Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I'm trying to write a dynamic linq query like:

```
var q = obj.Where("message.Contains('hello')");
```

I know it works for

```
var q = obj.Where(o => o.message.Contains('hello'));
```

but i'm looking for dynamic linq solution

Thanks.

Comment: what part needs to be changable? message or "hello" ?

Answer (score 16):

Found my answer now.

```
var q = obj.Where("message.Contains(@0)", "hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't what you are looking for, but just as a point to consider:

Depending on how many various kinds of operation you expect to perform, I would create a switch statement to handle this.

As an example, some pseudocode using an enum:

*(OperationType is an Enum if desired)*

```
private object example(OperationType optype, Object obj, String match)
{
   var q;
   switch (optype)
        {
        case OperationType.Contains:
            q = obj.Where(o => o.message.Contains(match));
        break;
        case OperationType.EndsWith:
            q = obj.Where(o => o.message.EndsWith(match));
        break;
        case OperationType.StartsWith:
            q = obj.Where(o => o.message.StartsWith(match));
        break;
    }
    return q;
}
```

Comment: Hi JYelton, thanks for your reply. Actually I'm looking for some answers like what Mike proposed. But Mike's expression doesnt work.